# Is an argument that contains a fallacy invalid?

Tags: fallacies

The argument in question is the following:

Penguins are black and white
Some old tv shows are black and white
Therefore, some penguins are old tv shows.

I believe this is an example of the undistributed middle fallacy. I've been told it's still valid. Is this true or not?

Comment: Maybe change the title to indicate you are asking about a particular argument and fallacy? There are _deductive_ fallacies, and arguments utilizing them as inferences will be invalid. But, more commonly, people have in mind so-called "informal fallacies" and there is no general connection between those fallacies and the validity of a deductive argument. Typically they'll be appealed to as reasons to believe the premises are true, so they are more likely to call into question a deductive argument's _soundness_ than _validity_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not **valid**.

You can see by formalizing it:

1. All P are BW
2. Some T are BW
3. Therefore, Some P are T.

We cannot infer the conclusion. For a graphical proof with venn diagrams, see AII - form two from [this link.](http://www.butte.edu/resources/interim/wmwu/iLogic/2.5/iLogic_2_5.html)

Comment: Thank you. I have another question.
I'm also being told "inductive premises can't give a deductive conclusion".
Is that true?

Comment: The wording is a bit strange on that, but I'd say that's probably true. (deductive and inductive are two forms of arguments -- rather than types of premises and conclusions -- properly speaking, but it's fair to say that an inductive argument's conclusion never has the properties we associate with  deductive argument's conclusion).

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. Is the premise "All men are mortal" not inferred from through inductive reasoning, but the conclusion "Socrates is a man" through deductive reasoning?

Comment: As used in the standard argument "All men are mortal. Socrates is a man. Socrates is mortal", "all men are mortal" is a premise a in deductive argument. / If instead we are inferring (inductively) that all men are mortal, then it could be the conclusion of an inductive argument "A was a man and died. B was a man and died. C was a man and died ... Ergo, All men are mortal." But whether something is *inductive* or *deductive* refers to the form of the argument -- not tot the statement itself.

Comment: "all men are mortal" seems to be claim whose truth rests on an empirical determination, but this does not mean it cannot be premise in a deductive argument. It merely means we cannot know merely deductively whether the premise is true.

Comment: And if it's truth rests on empirical determination, is that not inductive reasoning that we have used?

Comment: Yes... but you need to attend very carefully to the distinctions I've mentioned above (but again, it would be better to this as a new question rather than have me explain piece-meal point by point in comments).

Comment: My father says that the scar on my top lip is due to me falling from inside a basket as a child. I have to accept his authority in this matter, he was there... so his argument is correct. Except that his testimony is contradicted by my mother.

Comment: I'm completely lost. Did you comment on the wrong thing?

Comment: Argument from authority is a fallacy. But that doesn'r mean the authority is wrong. And vice-versa witness testimony is key to jurisprudence, but it doesn't mean it is not just a fallacy.

Comment: As you said. The answer is no. But i'd add that a good argument would not contain fallacies. But that depends on your rhetorical style. All covered ad-nauseum in Plato's Republic.